# Best practice to store and access Bootstrap in Wicket

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wicket, include-path

This is a real basic question and I know there are multiple good ways to access it, but is there something close to a "Best practice" for storing and accessing Bootstrap in Wicket?
Right now the structure is like this:

[image: Tree of project]

copy&pasting it as text gives not good results.
Is **webapp** the right place to store the bootstrap folder? 
And how would you define an accessible variable for the whole project? 
 Would you include the bootstrap in .html or with a property from wicket in the .java?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296074/using-javascript-bootstrap-in-wicket .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.agilecoders.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-bootstrap-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.agilecoders.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-bootstrap-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.agilecoders.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-bootstrap-themes</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So I think there is no need to set up your bootstrap at your own and you can reuse the existing components.

Just add `Bootstrap.install(this);` do you `init()`-method.

Comment: Someone answered this already, but seems to have deleted the answear, nevertheless thank you :)